# Table name not showing in relation view in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database named `flk_embriodery`. It contains two tables.

1. user
2. countries
   I created user table from phpmyadmin but generated countried table from mysql query. But interestingly countries table is not showing in relation view of user table.
   [image]

As it is clear that countries table is not showing up in the table list in relation view of user. How can i add it to the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not showing in the list because this table was not an `InnoDB`. To change it to InnoDB follow the steps
1. Go to table you want to change.
2. Go to operations tab
3. Under Table Options you can see the storage engine. Select the InnoDB and save it.
Problem Solved